# How to correctly lock StringBuilder so it would not throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, multithreading, stringbuilder

I have read multiple posts both on stack-overflow and elsewhere that StringBuilder is not Thread safe and when accessed (read / written to) from multiple threads should be locked: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555335/stringbuilder-crash-with-argumentoutofrangeexception), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564486/system-argumentoutofrangeexception-parameter-name-chunklength-at-system-text-st), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593842/why-is-this-causing-an-argumentoutofrangeexception-when-using-parallel-for). I'm unclear about how to lock my Stringbuilder instances - in particular how many locks should be added and where.

I have the following code (snippet-ed):

```
    class MemoryTracker
    {
        private Process extProc    { get; set; }
        private StringBuilder sb   { get; set; }

        internal int trackByIP(string ip)
        {
             ...
             ...
             sb = new StringBuilder();
             extProc.OutputDataReceived  += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e)  => sb.Append(e.Data + "\n"));
             extProc.ErrorDataReceived   += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e)  => sb.Append(e.Data + "\n"));

             extProc.Start();
             extProc.PriorityClass       = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
             ...
             ...
        }

        string getDataWStartEndPttrn(StringBuilder data, string strPttr, string endPttr, string extendedTerminator)
        {
             string s = data.ToString(); // <-- THROWS ArgumentOutOfRangeException 

             int si = getStartIdx(s, strPttr, patternDiff(strPttr, endPttr));
             int se = getEndIdx(s, endPttr, patternDiff(endPttr, strPttr));

             if (se >= 0 && si >= 0)
             {
                 string s1 = s.Substring(si, se - si);

                 string sTMP = s.Substring(se);
                 string s2 = s.Substring(se, sTMP.IndexOf(extendedTerminator));

                 return s1 + s2;
             }

             return "";
        }
```

Having placed the lock I still see the same error thrown.

```
class MemoryTracker
{
    private Process extProc    { get; set; }
    private StringBuilder sb   { get; set; }
    private Object thisLock = new Object();


    string getDataWStartEndPttrn(StringBuilder data, string strPttr, string endPttr, string extendedTerminator)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
             string s = data.ToString() ; // <-- STILL THROWS ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
        }
 ...
 ...
```

**QUESTION**: How do I correctly think about where to place the lock / locks? There is no place where I explicitly create threads, so I assumed it would be a thread-safe usage of the `StringBuilder.toString();`

Comment: You should also lock around 2 `sb.Append` statements.

Comment: That's the wrong use of the lock.  You lock around the use of a particular object.  In this case you would want to lock the string builder.  It appears you are passing in string builder as a parameter, which means the lock does nothing too prevent it from being accessed by a different thread. every non thread safe operation on the String builder needs to be locked, (usually anthing that modifies the contents of sb)

Comment: Thanks a lot, my idea was that I should probably lock on both append() and the .toString() calls. But maybe just one is enough (for the appends) ?

Comment: I believe the append should be enough.  Not sure if you need to worry about protecting against reading while its being written too.

Comment: You need to lock over both reads and writes.

Comment: I seem to miss a lot of points about locking - I have wrapped the appends(); and `.toString()` like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/uWb3w0Ti - I have created two separate lock for this - no idea if that is correct:
`private Object thisLock1 = new Object();`
`private Object thisLock2 = new Object();`

Comment: Yes you miss a lot of points (I'd say whole point) of locking. Create _one_ lock object (or lock string builder itself), and lock like this: `new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e)  => { lock (_sbLock) {sb.Append(e.Data + "\n"); }});`, not like you are doing now.

Comment: @Evk - can you put your suggestions into an answer for this question shortly explaining why my approach would not work compared to yours (i) why both reads and writes need to be locked (ii)? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution

Create thread safe wrapper around the StringBuilder use it instead the current. This will encapsulate the sync logic within the wrapper class. I think is a bit better this way, instead of locking in methods which use the StringBuilder class.

Use [ReaderWriteLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows several threads to access the code block when a reader lock is aquired an only single thread to access when write lock is aquired. Simply if several threads tries to use `.ToString()` method this will be fine, and if meanwile some other threads tries to use `.Append()` concurently, this thread will wait all other threads with read (`.ToString()`) to finish.

Here is very basic impl, it should be good starting point.

```
public class ThreadSafeStringBuilder 
{
   private readonly StringBuilder core = .....
   private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim sync = ....

   public void Append(String str) {
      try {
         this.sync.EnterWriterLock();
         this.core.Append(str);
      }
      finally {
         this.sync.ExitWriterLock()
      }
    }

  public override ToString() {
    try {
       this.sync.EnterReadLock();
       return this.core.ToString();
    }
    finnaly {
       this.sync.ExitReadLock()
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use the thread safe wrapper without the need to sync the access to it everywhere.

**EDIT 2017-12-18**: Suggestion from the comments. You should perform some perf. test. For a simple scenario [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) is more appropriate (check your worst case, like how many threads you expect to read or write ... etc, check also best case ... etc). In regards to the code, just replace the try, finnaly statements with lock statments, and the lock for both `.Append()` and `.ToString()` should lock on the same object.

Comment: ReaderWriterLock is efficient only if there's a lot of contention on the reading, and very little on the writing. In OP's scenario, it's almost certain that lock will perform better, and with less complexity

Comment: Thanks Vasil, it's nice to know the alternatives as well.

Comment: @KevinGosse, you are right. Added an edit to include your suggestion.